# what's the Difference between javac file.java and javac file*java in terminal?

Tags: java, javac

I want to know the difference between the command `javac filename.java` and `javac filename*java`

this is for running a mapreduce job

my terminal is opened in the code directory with 3 files: WCount.java, WCountMap.java WCountReduce.java

Comment: `filename*java` matches all files starting with `filename` and ending with `java`.

Comment: This question is really a question about how the command shell works.  It would be better asked / answered on https://superuser.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: What Stephen C said.  javac doesn’t implement wildcard pattern matching;  the command shell expands wildcard patterns, and javac ends up receiving an explicit list of files.

Answer (score 1):

***javac file.java*** will compile a single file "file.java"

***javac file*java*** will try to compile all files which name starts with *file* and ends with *java*.

In you case ***javac WCount*java*** will compile all your 3 files and is equivalent to ***javac WCount.java WCountMap.java WCountReduce.java***

However, be careful as Java file should end with ".java". Doing *javac filename*java* may try to compile files like filenamejava or filenameXXXjava (without the .) which will raise an error.
Therefore better to use .java in the pattern: ***javac file*.java***

Cheers!